# Correct method for calling a callback function with "this"

Tags: javascript, callback, this, babeljs

Is this context valid for calling a callback function with the correct "this" context?

`data.on('load', doSomething.call(this));`

Or would it be better to use an additional arrow function (yes, I'm using babel to compile.

```
data.on('load', () => {
  doSomething.call(this);
});
```

Both seem to have the same result in Chrome but haven't checked other browsers. Is there a best practice or is one way better supported than another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will call `doSomething` immediately, and assign the returned value as the event listener:

```
data.on('load', doSomething.call(this));
```

You probably want [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) instead:

```
data.on('load', doSomething.bind(this));
```

Your arrow function would work too.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to create a function, using the `this` value you expect.

`bind` creates a function to call later, `call` only invokes the function and gives the result.

`data.on('load', doSomething.bind(this));`

To answer your question about arrow syntax, while that is functionally similar to call: `()=> { doSomething.call(this) }`, the generated code has an additional layer of closure.

```
function() {
    doSomething.call(this);
}.bind(this);
```

Doing it this way will have a small performance penalty, though it should be negligible.